# Internal debug console doesn't accept my input

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I enter my input in the internal debugging console (number, for example) I get the message "Unable to perform this action because the process is running." (there is no problem with the output), but when I toggle external console (Windows console) in launch.json I don't encounter any problems.

I've read some documentary about the debugging in VSC (for example code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/debugging) but there is nothing about it. Am I not supposed to enter input there? Also, my output shows only in debugging console, is that normal as well? I can't enter my input through terminal either. Even if I start without debugging situation doesn't change. If I use the extension "C/C++ Compile Run" then normal internal terminal is created and I can interact with it.

My launch.json configuration

```json
        "name": "g++.exe build and debug active file",
        "type": "cppdbg",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
        "args": [],
        "stopAtEntry": false,
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
        "environment": [],
        "internalConsoleOptions": "openOnSessionStart",
        "externalConsole": false,
        "MIMode": "gdb",
        "miDebuggerPath": "C:\\MinGW\\bin\\gdb.exe",
        "setupCommands": [
            {
                "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                "ignoreFailures": true
            }
        ],
        "preLaunchTask": "g++.exe build active file"
```

My tasks.json:

```json
  "type": "shell",
  "label": "g++.exe build active file",
  "command": "C:\\MinGW\\bin\\g++.exe",
  "args": [
    "-g",
    "${file}",
    "-o",
    "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
  ],
  "options": {
    "cwd": "C:\\MinGW\\bin"
  },
  "problemMatcher": [
    "$gcc"
  ],
  "group": {
    "kind": "build",
    "isDefault": true
  }
```

c_cpp_properties.json:

```json
        "name": "Win32",
        "includePath": [
            "${workspaceFolder}/**"
        ],
        "defines": [
            "_DEBUG",
            "UNICODE",
            "_UNICODE"
        ],
        "windowsSdkVersion": "10.0.17763.0",
        "compilerPath": "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.16.27023/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe",
        "cStandard": "c11",
        "cppStandard": "c++17",
        "intelliSenseMode": "msvc-x64"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know debug console does not support to read input from console in c++ program. Only possible solution is use to use external terminal by setting ***true*** to ***externalConsole*** attribute.

[Official document](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/nodejs-debugging#_node-console) says to configure ***console*** attribute as ***integratedTerminal*** for Node.js programming. But no such provision for c++ program.

There is a similar [open issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-go/issues/219) for go programming. May be vscode team would have this in their backlog.